# Is it possible to determine the value of a matrix element given the dominant eigenvalue and all other elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, biology

I'm working on a population dynamics model and have a matrix of vital rates representing the survival and fecundity of different life stages of the animal which are set out in a 6 x 6 matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 4\\ 
0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.8 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & x
\end{pmatrix}

I also have a vector of initial population sizes:

\begin{pmatrix}
10\\ 
20\\ 
25\\ 
25\\ 
70\\ 
80
\end{pmatrix}

I already have an estimate for the **x** element in the matrix which allows me to calculate the population growth rate or dominant eigenvalue lambda. I was wondering if it's possible to calculate what value *should* **x** take if I want a lambda of 1 which is of biological relevance to the growth rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix you gave has characteristic polynomial
$$ p(\lambda ) = \lambda ^6 - x \lambda^5 - 0.504 \lambda + 0.504 x - 0.6048 $$
A necessary condition for $1$ to be an eigenvalue of the matrix is that $p(1) = 0$. This gives us an equation for $x$:

$$0 = 1 - x -0.504 + 0.504x - 0.6048$$
Solving for $x$ we get
$$x = -0.219355 $$
Not sure if that value makes sense biologically, as all the other entries are positive, but if you want an eigenvalue of $1$ for the matrix, you'll have to go with that $x$.

Comment: Hi, that's fine, I didn't supply the exact data I'm working with. I just wasn't sure of how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: @ManassaMauler You're welcome, though it would be more in the site's spirit if you'd upvote answers you like and accept the one you feel gives the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if negative values of $x$ make sense for your model (perhaps not), but I got $x\simeq-0.22$. For that $x$, there are only two real eigenvalues, one of which is (very nearly) $1$; the other one is about $-0.85$.

Comment: Hi, that's fine, I didn't supply the exact data I'm working with. I just wasn't sure of how to do it. Thank you